# Lifecycle hooks in safari mobile and ios app don’t work

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic5

None of the lifecycle hooks work in safari mobile or ios app.

NgOnInit and ionViewDidLoad and any of the other lifecycle hooks, they all work on the desktop and android app, but not in the ios side. Even if its the very first time visiting the page.

But, if i tap/click anywhere on the screen, then everything loads in exactly as desired.

ALSO, if I navigate to the page a second time or reload the page, everything is there just like I wanted.

any suggestions? I’m not receiving any errors.

I’m grabbing some info from back4apps’s database, and just trying to display it when the page opens.

typescript

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.unhide();
  }

unhide() {
this.news.get("deEygHXCR9").then((gameScore) => {
    this.memberList = gameScore.get("announcements");
  }, (error) => {
  });
}
```

html

```
<ion-item class = "backColor2">
      <ion-textarea class="textAreaHeight" readonly="true" auto-grow="true" type="text" name="memberList" [(ngModel)]="memberList" ></ion-textarea>
      </ion-item>
```

Like I said, android and chrome work fine. Any suggestions for fixes or alternative methods? I’m using ionic 5 and angular 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not the most experienced programmer… but I found the issue eventually… It wasn’t the lifecycle hooks. It was because I was displaying data from a third party and in order for my screen to update it using ngmodel after retrieving the data, I had to run it inside of an NgZone… like this…

```
import {  NgZone } from '@angular/core';


constructor(
public ngZone: NgZone,
  ) {}



async unhide() {
this.news.get("deEygHXCR9").then((gameScore) => {
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.memberList = gameScore.get("announcements");
});
  }, (error) => {
  });
}
```

Thank you to everyone that took a look though!